# Do all my pages need to be mobile friendly?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, mobile, mobile-friendly-tool

I’m having trouble with Google Console accepting some pages as mobile friendly. My main page works fine, as do most of the important pages.

I have tried spacing things apart to the point that they look ridiculous, but nothing works. Some of the pages are very simple, with only a few words and using the same css that the working pages use.

Is it important that my entire site is mobile friendly?

Comment: Why are you trying to space things apart?  Are you getting "clickable elements too close together?"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes, I’m also getting “ Content wider than screen”, and I don’t know why. I have a sliding menu that hides outside of the screen on every page, so that can’t be it.

Comment: There are tools that can help find these things.   Have you been using the responsive layout in chrome or firefox dev tools?   There are also tools like https://blogiestools.com/web-page-clickable-elements-checker-tool/ that highlight clickable elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google evaluates mobile-friendliness on a page by page basis, not for your site as a whole.   Having some pages that are not mobile-friendly will not hurt the rankings of your mobile-friendly pages.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definetely. Most of the visitors use a mobile device. This is the reason why Google started to focuse on mobile devices (mobile-centric indexing by default since July, 2019).

Make sure that your website is fully responsive by using the right media queries. A well-structured layout using HTML5 with semantic elements would also help on it. Design matters, so it's all about HTML5 and CSS3, with a little of JavaScript when it's necessary.

Comment: My website only uses HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript (except for a little PHP for the contact form). I have even given every div a background color to see if it is running off the screen, but I can’t find anything. Will a few pages effect the SEO of my entire site?

Comment: No. Google evaluates the pages one by one, not by site. Your mobile-friendly pages will not be affected by the other pages. I think the same that @Stephen_Ostermiller said. Actually, this information was explained by John Mueller on Youtube some months ago.